# How can I make my device to last longer?

Tags: science-based, biology, technology

I am writing a hard science book and there is a watch used by the main character. A glow-in-the-dark watch with GFP (green fluorescent protein) in real life this protein only lasts 26h approx. how could I make my watch last longer with the same protein, is it possible to modify this protein to make it last longer?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello @herls, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. (a) If you roll your mouse over the [tag:science-based] and [tag:hard-science] tags, you'll discover they are mutually exclusive. [tag:Hard-science] does not mean what you think it means. That tag is ruthless and serves a specific purpose. Please read it carefully, because answers that don't conform are under threat of deletion (and if you don't need the detail it demands, there's no reason to use it).

Comment: (b) I would also like to point out that you probably haven't thought through what you're asking for. Anyone who could provide a [tag:science-based] answer for extending the viability of GFP would have a multi-million (if not multi-billion) dollar idea - and you should not expect them to post such an idea here. The "Hard Science" science fiction genre does not demand that every aspect of science in the book be provable today, in Real Life. It requires the *consequences* of the application of science to be realistic. Even *The Expanse* doesn't explain everything - because they can't.

Comment: I am of the opinion that what you are interested in is not what you have written. The watch will almost certainly last very very much longer than 26 hours. Nobody would ever buy a watch which has to be thrown away after one single day of use.

Comment: The major issue is the fluorescent bit. fluorescence means it *needs a light* source to drive the fluorescence.   If the character is in a cave for example he will not see the watch display until they shine em of the right frequency range of upon the watch.  Perhaps you want phosphorescent material that has a time delay component. Or perhaps a bioluminescence system?

Answer (score 4):

## Have a glow in the dark bacteria

The obvious way to extend the lifespan is to splice it into some sort of bacteria, probably e-coli, and regularly feed it a small dose of sugar and food. This would extend the lifespan substantially. Once every week, or every couple of weeks if you're ok with it being a bit dimmer, you give it some sugar and it stays alive.

You can get one that smells of [lemon and bananas](https://www.technologyreview.com/2006/11/03/100253/bizarre-bacterial-creations/) with a bit of genetic engineering, or any of a variety of smells. There are numerous strains of e-coli to suit your tastes.

Also, the half life of the wild strain is 26 hours. That means the glowiness will half every 26 hours. It doesn't mean it will vanish.

Comment: I like this idea. Safer than radium but with a consequence that adds just the right touch of imperfection.

Comment: Just going to say e-coli would be a poor choice due to what habitat they prefer (gut like) and their waste products.(they tend to stink like sewer).   I mean yes entirely possible, But I would think I luxury watch designer would want something else.

Comment: I noted that they could use a custom ecoli that smells nice.

Comment: @GaultDrakkor E. coli grow pretty much anywhere where it's comfortably warm and the right nutrients are available. They like 37 degrees C best but should be fine also in the warmth of a watch pressed against a wrist. And I don't think the amount you'd put in the watch hands would smell that much.

Answer (score 1):

A frame challenge, rather then increasing functional duration of a protein (which aside GFP will almost certainly not do what you want it to do), increase the supply of the desired protein in a bioluminescence system.

#### Bioluminescence system

Put the factories on/in the watch. This would be accomplished by have some engineered lichens that likes living in certain structures that are part of the watch. The lichens could be boosted with a glucose feed supplied some how from a reservoir in the watch.  The glowing effect should then reasonably last months to years if glucose supply is maintained.

Specifying lichen because they are tough and less likely to have overgrowth issues unlike some alternatives. But there would be many candidate fungus or bacteria possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

**Watch is disposable.**

It is fading by the end of the day.  He uses a new one the next day.  Old watch goes in the sendback bin, along with the used lapel carnation from that day, and his worn paper socks and undershorts.